# SQL Show available stock depending on the weight and first 4 characters of code

Tags: sql, sql-server

DDL and DML:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Product 
(
    id int not null,
    code varchar(20),
    description varchar(40),
    searchref1 varchar(20),
    weightKG decimal(10, 2)
);

INSERT INTO Product (id, code, description, searchref1, weightKG)
VALUES (1, '0001101', 'ProductOne', '1kg', 1),
       (2, '0001050', 'ProductOne', '500g', 0.5),
       (3, '0001400', 'ProductOne', '10 x 1kg', 10),
       (4, '0080101', 'ProductTwo', '1kg', 1),
       (5, '0080050', 'ProductTwo', '500g', 0.5),
       (6, '0001WIP', 'ProductOne Work in progress', '1kg', 1),
       (7, '0080WIP', 'ProductTwo Work in progress', '1kg', 1);
 
CREATE TABLE SalesOrderLine 
(
    id int not null,
    productID int,
    requiredQty int
);

INSERT INTO SalesOrderLine (id, productID, requiredQty)
VALUES (1, 1, 21), (2, 2, 5), (3, 3, 8), (4, 5, 1);

CREATE TABLE Stock 
(
    id int not null,
    productID int,
    inStock int
);

INSERT INTO Stock (id, productID, inStock)
VALUES (1, 6, 10), (2, 7, 2);
```

SQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a68d49/28

I have a `SalesOrderLine` table like so:

```
SELECT
    code, searchref1, requiredQty, weightKG
FROM 
    SalesOrderLine sol
JOIN 
    Product P ON p.id = sol.productid;

code       searchref1     requiredQty   weightKG
------------------------------------------------
0001101    1kg            21            1
0001050    500g           5             0.5
0001400    10 x 1kg       8             10
0080050    500g           1             0.5
```

I can now then group the product codes by first 4 codes. Whilst I do that, I can get the total sum of `weightKG * requiredQty`.

**Query**

```
SELECT
    LEFT(code, 4) AS code, SUM(weightKG * requiredQty) AS TotalKg
FROM  
    SalesOrderLine sol
JOIN 
    Product P ON p.id = sol.productid
GROUP BY 
    LEFT(code, 4)
```

Result:

```
code    TotalKg
---------------
0001    103.5
0080    0.5
```

So far I know how much `kg` in total is needed for a particular product.

**Problem**: I am now stuck with this..

I have another table called `Stock`:

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(p.code, 4) AS code, p.searchref1, inStock  
FROM 
    stock s 
JOIN 
    product p ON s.productID = p.id;

code    searchref1  inStock
---------------------------
0001    1kg         10
0080    1kg         2
```

I now then need to have this output of the table:

```
code    TotalKg   inStock1KgOnly  remaining
-------------------------------------------
0001    103.5     10              93.5          
0080    0.5       0               0.5
```

The reason `0080` is showing as `0`, is because on the SalesOrderLine there are no `1kg` orders and is not relevant to the stock. The remaining shows how much stock needs to be produced to create specifically `1kg`.

The `remaining` column is just a simple calculation `TotalKg - inStock1KgOnly`.

My attempt at a query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.code, t1.totalKg, 
    t2.inStock AS inStock1KgOnly, 
    (t1.TotalKg - t2.inStock) AS Remaining 
FROM
    (SELECT
         LEFT(code, 4) AS code, SUM(weightKG * requiredQty) AS TotalKg
     FROM 
         SalesOrderLine sol
     JOIN 
         Product P ON p.id = sol.productid
     GROUP BY 
         LEFT(code, 4)) t1 
JOIN 
    (SELECT LEFT(p.code, 4) as Code, inStock
     FROM product p
     JOIN stock s ON s.productID = p.id) t2 ON (t1.code = t2.code)
```

**Output**

```
code    totalKg inStock1KgOnly  Remaining
------------------------------------------
0001    103.5   10              93.5
0080    0.5     2               -1.5
```

Comment: Start with `product` as the driving table, inner join `stock`, left join `SalesOrderLine`. You could also write it as a right join, but that will just give you a migraine

Comment: Where would you create these joins in the current query?

Comment: Thinking about it I'm confused. Do you want all products or only 1kg products in the result, and should we group by `code` or `left(code,4)`? Is this include products with no orders or only products with orders? Only products with stock or even without?

Comment: @Charlieface https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcQwr.png This is the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to infer requirements not explicitly explained.

This should cover you...

```
WITH TEMP_Product AS
(
SELECT
  p.Id AS ProductId
  ,LEFT(p.code, 4) AS Code
  ,p.weightKg AS WeightKg
FROM Product p
)
,TEMP_SalesOrderLine AS
(
SELECT 
  p.Code
  ,SUM(l.RequiredQty * p.WeightKg) AS TotalKg
FROM SalesOrderLine l
INNER JOIN TEMP_Product p ON l.ProductId = p.ProductId
GROUP BY p.Code
)
,TEMP_Stock AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT
  p.Code
  ,s.InStock
  ,SUM(s.InStock * p.WeightKg) OVER (PARTITION BY p.Code) AS InStockKg
FROM Stock s
INNER JOIN TEMP_Product p ON p.ProductId = s.ProductId
)
,TEMP_Summary AS
(
SELECT
  l.Code
  ,l.TotalKg
  ,FLOOR(l.TotalKg) AS FloorKg
  ,s.InStockKg
  ,(l.TotalKg - s.InStockKg) AS Delta
FROM TEMP_SalesOrderLine l
INNER JOIN TEMP_Stock s ON l.Code = s.Code
)
SELECT
  s.Code
  ,s.TotalKg
  ,CASE WHEN (s.FloorKg < 1) THEN 0 
        ELSE CASE WHEN (s.Delta >= 0) THEN s.InStockKg
                  ELSE s.TotalKg END 
   END AS InStockKg
  ,CASE WHEN (s.FloorKg < 1) THEN s.TotalKg
        ELSE CASE WHEN (s.Delta < 0) THEN 0 
                  ELSE s.Delta END
   END AS Remaining
FROM TEMP_Summary s;
```

RESULTS:

0.5

```
INSERT INTO SalesOrderLine (id, productID, requiredQty)
VALUES (1, 1, 21), (2, 2, 5), (3, 3, 8), (4, 5, 1);
```

[image: 0.5]

1.0

```
INSERT INTO SalesOrderLine (id, productID, requiredQty)
VALUES (1, 1, 21), (2, 2, 5), (3, 3, 8), (4, 5, 2);
```

[image: 1.0]

2.5

```
INSERT INTO SalesOrderLine (id, productID, requiredQty)
VALUES (1, 1, 21), (2, 2, 5), (3, 3, 8), (4, 5, 5);
```

[image: 2.5]

Comment: `0080` shows as `2` whereas it should say `0`. Because there is `0` of `1kg` ordered.

Comment: Updated with inferred logic.  Let me know how this works out for you.

Comment: Are you able to assist with this. If I run this query `INSERT INTO SalesOrderLine (id, productID, requiredQty)
VALUES (1, 1, 21), (2, 2, 5), (3, 3, 8), (4, 5, 1);`, for Code `001` Column `InStockKg` shows as `103.50` but it should be `101`. This is because, of code `001` sizes of `1kg` ordered in total is `101kg` not including the `500g`. Hope this helps https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcQwr.png The `500g` product will just go into remaining column